# How to load a custom html module using ajax-call joomla 2.5

Tags: jquery, module, joomla2.5

I have in my html page a link with class name ="flyer" and href="MY_HREF".
When the user click's in the link I want to load a "custom html"  module with specific ID.
Can you please advise me how will be the syntax of the  MY_HREF.

For example http://www.mywebsite/com_custom/id=ID.html  ???

Below I have the ajax call:

```
    jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false  
    });    
    var portfolioItemURL = "";  
    jQuery(".flyer").click(
        function(){
            portfolioItemURL = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("MY_HREF") + '?tmpl=component&type=raw';
            jQuery("#ajaxCallContainer").load(portfolioItemURL);
        }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the solution.

1)We **create our html module** and we **set a custom position** e.x myposition

2)We **create  an article** and we **load our module** {loadposition  myposition}.

> *Note that every article has its own ID and ALIAS.*

3)The final url for our ajax call is: http://myurl.gr/ID-ALIAS.html?tmpl=component&type=raw

Note that if you add any content to the article you will get the html of the article + the html of the module.

The ajax call code is:

MY_HREF = ID-ALIAS.html

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup ({

        dataType: "html",
        cache: false  
    });    
    var portfolioItemURL = "";  
    jQuery(".flyer").click(
        function(){
            portfolioItemURL = jQuery(this).find("a").attr("MY_HREF") + '?tmpl=component&type=raw';
            jQuery("#ajaxCallContainer").load(portfolioItemURL);
        }
);
```

kisses from Kalymnos,Greece