# joomla 2.5 module: how to call a php function like javascript onclick?

Tags: php, function, joomla, module, onclick

In joomla 2.5 module helper.php have a function

```
function hello() 
{ 
   echo " something my code";
}
```

In my tmpl/default.php have a text loadFunction.

```
echo " loadFunction";
```

I want, when someone click the text loadFunction then will be run function hello()   . Like javascript onclick event system. How to do it in php ? Pls help

Comment: you can build an ajax request for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla I suppose you have included jQuery.

[Definition and Usage](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[Joomla how to make an ajax call to an helper.php module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332883/joomla-how-to-make-an-ajax-call-to-an-helper-php-module)

[How to make an Ajax request in Joomla Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478108/how-to-make-an-ajax-request-in-joomla-component)

[How to load a custom html module using ajax-call joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695025/how-to-load-a-custom-html-module-using-ajax-call-joomla-2-5)